Is it possible to return an empty slot from JavaScript's map() function?
This site has a similar question: Possible to push empty slot to an array? I want to know if it's possible for the Array.prototype.map callback to return an empty slot.
I tried this but it returns undefined instead:


console.log([1, 2, 3].map(() => {}));



I want to return empty slots so that I can simply call flat() on the return value to remove them. flat() does not remove undefined or null values.
I'm aware of the .filter(Boolean) trick, but I don't like that solution because 0 is falsey, and I've never intended to remove that as a side effect of removing null/undefined elements: in my experience, .filter(Boolean) is a ticking time bomb in one's code.

What does "empty slot" mean if not undefined?

@Pointy see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#sparse_arrays (I added it to the question)

Does it have to be map ?

You can easily achieve this by create an array with the same length and a simple for loop

I don't understand what you mean by "I want to return empty slots so that I can simply call flat() on the return value to remove them.", what exactly is the goal? flat() is meant to be called on arrays of arrays.

@Bergi True, maybe there is a more suitable method, but I think in other programming languages it also removes "blanks"

@DanielKaplan I guess it does that in JS as well, ignoring "blanks" (empty slots) like other modern array methods, but it's definitely not its primary purpose and your usage here is very confusing. Your titular question could be answered with a simple "no", but if you tell us more about your actual goal we could suggest a suitable alternative.

console.log(Array([1, 2, 3].length)); does exactly what you tried in your code - if you want to "punch" emtpy slots into an array, delete array[index] is what you'll somehow want to do

@Bergi I would accept a simple "no" as the answer. I know lots of alternatives to solving my problem, but I wanted to know if JavaScript could do this specific thing (return empty slots from map).

I feel like the issue you're having is that map always returns the same length of array that it is operating on. I think the solution you want is a a reduce that skips null and undefined values.  Also filter(Boolean)  could just as easily be replaced by filter(x=> x!=null) 

@ScottZ Correct. Those are all alternatives I've considered. I'm not asking for a workaround, only if JavaScript has this capability.

.flatMap(() => []) is almost similar to what you're trying to do "I want to return empty slots so that I can simply call flat() on the return value to remove them"  (but it's clearer to use .filter() in my opinion)

I think the question would be better asked as can array.prototype.map create sparse arrays? And  the answer would be no.   Seems everyone is getting hung up on "empty slot".

@ScottZ Actually it can create sparse arrays, but only if the input array is already sparse. It will not convert a value into no value though.


I want to know if it's possible for the Array.prototype.map callback to return an empty slot.

No, this is not possible. A (callback) function always returns a value (or throws an exception), whereas an empty slot is "created" by the absence of a value. An empty slot is a property that does not exist despite being between 0 and the array's .length. The map() function always creates properties for the values returned from the calls to the callback function.

No it is not possible to return an empty slot from Array.prototype.map, because a reference to the array being built is not passed to map's  argument function, and empty slots are created by increasing the length of an array by setting it's length property, or using the delete operator on an element within the array.
Out of interest, here's an simple example of creating a sparse array by setting its length:


// create test array with  3 slots and populate the 1st and last slot

const testArray = [];
testArray.length = 3;
testArray[0] = 0;
testArray[2] = 2;

// check .flat() creates an array of length 2

const flatArray = testArray.flat();

console.log( "flatArray (length %s): ", flatArray.length, flatArray);



[Note: in the above code, the snippet console.log function does not appear to conform to the standard to log remaining arguments which follow formatting string arguments and the values which the format string consumes.]

A very ordinary alternative would be to iterate over an input array and push elements to be kept to an output array, or not push them if they are not required in flat array output.

This feels like what you are asking.  If not, what am I missing?
const arry = ["mary", "bob", 'frank']

const res = arry.flatMap(x => x === "bob" ? []:[x]) // res = ["mary", "frank"]



Edit
I think the hangup is that you're asking for empty slots, and then suggesting using array.prototype.flat to clean up those empty slots.  It feels like most know that flat concatenates nested arrays, but it also cleans up sparse arrays.
There seem to be only a few ways to create sparse arrays, and array.prototype.map is not one of them. Sparse Array

Yep, this is a good answer. It achieves the outcome I'm looking for, but as you've acknowledged, it does so without empty slots. Thanks!

Use an empty array instead:


console.log([1, 2, 3].map(() => []).flat());




I'm not sure why you are getting down voted. It might help if you: 1) explain how this answer works. I'm assuming an empty array has no empty slots, so the return value might be the outcome I'm looking for but for the wrong reasons. 2) Show how to do this with a more sophisticated predicate. e.g., put an if statement in your callback.
